# Rest API resource design for many-to-many relation

Tags: rest, entity-relationship, api-design

**Post** can be in many **Categories** and **Sections**.
**Category** and **Section** can have many **Posts**

To list **sections/categories** using:

```
GET /posts/categories
GET /posts/sections
```

seems to be better design than:

```
GET /categories
GET /sections
```

But how to ask for **Posts** from **sections/categories** ?

- This seems to be awkward (or maybe it isn't ?):

  `GET /posts/sections/{id}/posts`
- These can be problematic:

  `GET /posts?section={id}`

  because I already have couple filters, so I end with:

  `GET /posts?section={id}&filter1={f1}&filter2={f2}....`

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would use the query parameter approach to filter the posts collection given that it's a many to many relationship and the resources can be managed independently:

```
GET /posts?section={id}
```

And I would probably use the following mapping for categories and sections:

```
GET /categories
```

```
GET /sections
```

---

If, for example, a collection of posts belongs to just a *single* category, I would use:

```
GET /categories/{id}/posts
```

Comment: That looks clean, but I thought (and read somewhere), that good design practice is to have as few as possible "main" resources. So using: 
`GET /posts`
`GET /categories`
`GET /sections`

we have 3 main resources (posts, categories, sections), and using

`GET /posts`
`GET /posts/sections`
`GET /posts/categories`

we have only 1 main resource (posts). 

**Categories and sections are being used only in context of posts**

Comment: @msiakis **1.** Saying that you _"read [it] somewhere"_ is pretty vague and doesn't add much. **2.** _"Categories and sections are being used only in context of posts."_ But they can still be seen as main resources.